# Is it possible to search a query within wikipedia for only populated places?

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia

Is it possible to search a query within wikipedia for only populated places?

For example: when i write a query like `BELGIUM intitle:GEMBLOUX` or `BELGIUM GEMBLOUX`, I anticipate `Gembloux` page, where is a town in Belgium, in the first order but I get `Gembloux Abbey` page which is useless for my aim. I thought that if I can state it in the query retrieving only populated places, I can get what i want.

P.s.:I have already used DBpedia but I need to get the correct link in the first place in wikipedia search results and then I need to parse this page since DBpedia is not up to date for many cities...

Comment: Have you tried http://live.dbpedia.org/?

Comment: @svik as i see dbpedia has also many missing part as expected. For ex. i am trying to reach regions or states information for cities. They are existing in infoboxes but not in related dbpedia or dbpedia-live pages. Or i am missing very trivial thing? I have checked manually many cities such as Leuven Belgium etc. http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Leuven there is no region info

Comment: I think that's because the region info is not directly contained  in the article text, it's computed by the template from the NIS number. I *think* this could be added to DBPedia using a [custom mapping](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/Writing_Mappings/Templates#Custom_Mappings), but I don't know anything about those.

Comment: I thought so svick. Thanx for your consideration.

Comment: What information are you trying to _get_ about these places.  DBpedia can be used (as I showed in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21770695/1281433)) to find populated places whose names match a string.  Is there other information that you're trying to get?

Comment: Actually I am trying to reach only Gembloux not Gembloux Abbey. After getting the correct wikipedia page for Gembloux, i will extract region information from infobox since this info does not exist in related dbpedia page. But when I try to get the related wikipedia link Gembloux Abbey page comes first in the search results. In addition, thanks to your answer @Joshua I realized that Gembloux Abbey is also a populated place. So i think it hard to get always the exact link precisely. Finally, this is only an example of course i am dealing with many other places.

Comment: @user3198674 Well, in DBpedia, both are populated places, so if you're looking to exclude Gembloux Abbey, you'll need to find another way to distinguish it from Gembloux.  If you can pinpoint one, then it shouldn't be too hard to add it to the SPARQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use DBpedia to search for populated places.  In your case, you can use the [public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) retrieve populated places that have "Gembloux" in their name and the associated Wikipedia article with this query:

```
select distinct ?place ?wikipediaArticle where { 
  ?place a dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace ;
         rdfs:label ?label ;
         foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipediaArticle .

  filter( regex( ?label, "Gembloux" ))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?place%20?wikipediaArticle%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?place%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aPopulatedPlace%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3aisPrimaryTopicOf%20?wikipediaArticle%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20regex%28%20?label,%20%22Gembloux%22%20%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
place                                       wikipediaArticle
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Gembloux        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gembloux
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Gembloux_Abbey  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gembloux_Abbey
```

Comment: Thanx @Joshua for this simple approach.